# What are uses of Floating Action Button in Material Design Android

Tags: android

Floating Action Button in Material Design is more prevalent in major apps, what are the specific use cases where FAB is more better choice.

Comment: Its like a button do what you want to with that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating action buttons are `used for a special type of promoted action`. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the transferring anchor point.

Floating action buttons come in two sizes: the default and the mini. The size can be controlled with the `fabSize` attribute.

for more detail visit this :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Answer (score 0):

"A floating action button represents the primary action in an application."

Example action - add new contact for contact list view.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html